# Can I use python def in airflow? or is this not considered good practice?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

If I need to load multiple tables, can I create a python function like this or is it not considered good practice?

```
def bqLoad(task, table_id, fileList):
    load = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id = task,
        bucket = "bucket_name",
        destination_project_dataset_table="{}.{}.{}".format("project_id","dataset_id",table_id),
        source_format="PARQUET",
        source_objects = fileList,
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        dag=dag,
    )
    return load
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach is fine, and considered DRY (the principle aimed at reducing repetition of software, which you can read more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) or in [this book](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpp20/the-pragmatic-programmer-20th-anniversary-edition/) which is very good)

Furthermore, [the Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html) outlines a variety of best practices that you can have a read through if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to define a [Custom Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#creating-a-custom-operator) by extending any other `Operator`, could be something like this:

```py
class BigQueryLoadOperator(GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator):
    """
    Custom Operator..
    """

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 table_id,
                 fileList,
                 *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super(BigQueryLoadOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bucket = "bucket_name",
        self.destination_project_dataset_table = "{}.{}.{}".format(
            "project_id", "dataset_id", table_id),
        self.source_format = "PARQUET",
        self.source_objects = fileList,
        self.create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        self.write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        # Implement here the expected behavior
        # Take advantage from attributes and methods
        # from inherited operator
        pass
```

Consume it from your DAG with something like this:

```py
    load_to_bq_task = BigQueryLoadOperator(
        task_id='some_unique_id',
        table_id='table_unique_id',
        file_list=['file1','file2']
    )
```

Check the provided link for more details and examples. Good luck!